# Property 'inputItem' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' - Semantic-Ui, React, & Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using React, Typescript, and Semantic UI react components. I am trying to clear the input field after adding a successful item.
During `debugger` I can see the `event.currentTarget.inputName.value` which I want to set to an empty string.

I keep getting one of the following errors:

`Property 'inputItem' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

`Property 'inputItem' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'.  TS2339`

Method where typescript keeps populating the error.

```
 handleAdd(e: SyntheticEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.inputItem.value = "";
    console.log(e);
    // target.value = "";
    debugger;
    const items: any = this.state.items;
    this.setState({ items: [...items, this.state.item], item: "" });
  }
```

Semantic-UI Form

- Within **Form.Input** I have param called  `name="inputItem"` which is what I can see in the console.log/debugger by doing `e.target.inputItem` or `e.currentTarget.inputItem`

```
 public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Segment className="mt-5 main-segment">
          <Header className="flex-col">
            <span>Today </span>
            <span>{todaysDate()}</span>
            <span>{currentTime()}</span>
          </Header>
          <Form className="flex-row" onSubmit={this.handleAdd}>
            <Form.Input
              id="inputField"
              placeholder="add todo item"
              className="todo-input"
              name="inputItem"
              onChange={this.handleItemChange}
            />

            <Form.Button content="Add" name="add-item" primary />
          </Form>
          <div id="list-items">{this.renderItems()}</div>
        </Segment>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I am looking for a solution on how to make this work or a more optimized way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling e.persist() before accessing input value.

You can refer https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html for more info